# How to make spaces wider in vim?

Tags: vim, xterm

I recently installed the window manager awesome, and started to use xterm. While configuring the font, I came accross this webpage: https://cjshayward.com/terminal/printer.html
that makes the really good point that you don't have to make the font bigger to get more easily readable code, but only to make the spaces between words wider.

How can I achieve this in vim?

Comment: I would point out that the font in the first xterm screenshot at that link looks to be a 9px or 10px X11 `fixed` font. That particular (famous) font changes its shape dramatically just a little smaller, down at 8px, where everything suddenly becomes shorter in height and giving the appearance of being a little more spread out. Quite nice to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only hack I can think of is replacing every space character with its double-width companion, U+3000 ideographic space:

```
:%s/ /\=nr2char(0x3000)/g
```

You could use `:autocmd`s to undo this before, and redo after saving, but I wouldn't recommend this.

Unfortunately, the *conceal* feature only handles single-width characters so far. It would make for a far better workaround.

Comment: I tried this trick using \=nr2char(0x3000) and \u3000, but I always end up with double-width characters composed of a square and a space instead of double-width spaces. I added set encoding=utf-8 and set fileencodings=utf-8 in my .vimrc. locale says LANG=en_US.UTF-8 and my font is DejaVu Sans Mono. It doesn't change anything to launch xterm with the -u8 flag. Any idea of what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. Vim uses a fixed size per character (as it's running in a terminal), and therefore the only way to change this is to change the font or font size. To achieve a different character/letter spacing you'll need to either edit the font or choose another.

Comment: Some terminals support proportional fonts; specifically, I happen to know that `mlterm` and Emacs `M-x term` do... Not sure if running Vim inside of Emacs' M-x term is legally allowed, but there it is...

Answer (score 0):

@Ingo this is what I added to my .vimrc:

```
"doubles space in insert mode    
inoremap <space> <space><space>

if !exists("autocommands_loaded")
        let autocommands_loaded = 1

        "doubles spaces when reading file
        au bufRead *.cpp        silent %s/ /  /g

        "for :w
        au bufWritePre *.cpp    silent %s/  / /g
        au bufWritePost *.cpp   silent %s/ /  /g

        "for :wq
        au quitPre *.cpp        silent %s/  / /g
endif
```

Comment: One problem with this is that it will mess with error codes and such; for example your compiler or interpreter will say "line 42, column 100", but in your editor it will display as "line 42, column 112"...